# Need help creating extension method in C# with generics and lambda expression

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, extension-methods

I'm pulling all of the advanced features together for this one, but haven't worked with generics or lambda expressions very much:

Here's example usage of the method I want to create:

```
MyClass mc = null;
int x = mc.TryGetOrDefault(z => z.This.That.TheOther); // z is a reference to mc
// the code has not failed at this point and the value of x is 0 (int's default)
// had mc and all of the properties expressed in the lambda expression been initialized
// x would be equal to mc.This.That.TheOther's value
```

Here's as far as I've gotten, but Visual Studio is complaining:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't made your method generic in `TResult`. You want something like:

```
public static TResult TryGetOrDefault<TSource, TResult>
    (this TSource obj, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> expression)
```

Comment: You've just made this into an entirely new question Ronnie. I think Jon has answered the first one perfectly.

Comment: I thought the scope of the question centered around my end result and since StackOverflow touts itself as being wiki like, I could update the question. Wait for URL to my next ?

Comment: @Ronnie: You can edit an existing question - but you've asked a *new* question, which isn't the same thing at all.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help. I asked another question.